# How do I trace a linq query when using PredicateBuilder/AsExpandable?

Tags: linq, predicatebuilder

I am using PredicateBuilder, which means that I am using the AsExpandable extension method. The problem is that I can no longer Trace my SQL queries as the following error is thrown when I try to cast the query to ObjectQuery so that I can do a ObjectQuery.ToTraceString() call on it...

Unable to cast object of type 'LinqKit.ExpandableQuery`1[Genesis.Person]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend running a Dump() on your query in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), and using the SQL tab to see what SQL was generated.  Do do this, hook up LINQPad to your Entity Framework context, press F4 to include a reference to LinqKit.dll, and LinqKit as a namespace import.  Let me know if you need additional guidance in how to do this.

Comment: OK, I'll have a go at this tomorrow when I'm back at work but it seems like a reasonable way to get the SQL out...

Answer (score 3):

Use the following universal PredicateBuilder instead of LinqKit:

http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

Then ObjectQuery.ToTraceString() will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your precise problem but can you not run the trace on the SQL server instead using (eg profiler assuming MSSQL) ?

This would still allow you to see the executed queries and you could restrict it to be just your machine that is recorded...