# Generated SQL with PredicateBuilder, LINQPad and operator ANY

Tags: dump, linqpad, predicatebuilder, generated-sql

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517529/how-to-create-a-linq-to-entities-expression) a question about chaining conditions in Linq To Entities.
Now I use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and everything works fine.
I want to see the generated SQL and after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466511), I use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net).

This is my statement:

```
var predProduct = PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();
var predColorLanguage = PredicateBuilder.True<ColorLanguage>();

predProduct = predProduct.And(p => p.IsComplete);

predColorLanguage = predColorLanguage.And(c => c.IdColorEntity.Products.AsQueryable().Any(expr));

ColorLanguages.Where(predColorLanguage).Dump();
```

The code works in VS2008, compile and produce the correct result set, but in LinqPad, I've the following error:

```
NotSupportedException: The overload query operator 'Any' used is not Supported.
```

How can I see the generated SQL if LINQPad fails?

**EDIT**

If I write

```
var predColorLanguage = PredicateBuilder.True<ColorLanguage>();

predColorLanguage = predColorLanguage.And(c => c.IdColorEntity.Products.Any((p => p.IsComplete));

ColorLanguages.Where(predColorLanguage).Dump();
```

works... WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using LINQKit, you can make this work by calling Compile() on the expression that feeds the EntitySet, and then calling AsExpandable() on the main query:

```
var predProduct = PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();
var predColorLanguage = PredicateBuilder.True<ColorLanguage>();

predProduct = predProduct.And(p => p.IsComplete);

predColorLanguage = predColorLanguage.And (
  c => c.IdColorEntity.Products.Any(predProduct.Compile()));

ColorLanguages.AsExpandable().Where(predColorLanguage).Dump();
```

As [explained in the LINQKit article](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), the Compile method never actually runs: AsExpandable strips it out and modifies the expression tree so that it works with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: The problem is not in Visual Studio, but in LinqPad.
In Visual Studio it works with no problem.
I've tried your solution with no luck.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? And if so, are you choosing 'Custom EF Context' when connecting in LINQPad? If you instead connect directly to a database in LINQPad, you're using LINQ to SQL which could account for the difference.