# How to use predicate builder with linq2sql and OR operator

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, predicate, predicatebuilder

I have two tables (TABLE1, TABLE2 - unique i know) that has a 1-to-many relationship respectively and a foreign key between ID columns of both tables.

Using **linq2sql** I am trying to select all **TABLE1** entries such that their corresponding **TABLE2** values contains at least 1 item in the list I pass it.

Here's some sample code I was using in **LINQPad** (awesome program) to test it out however am getting the error **NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Any'.**

```
long[] items = { 3, 5, 8 };
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<TABLE2>();

foreach (long i in items)
{
    long t = i;
    predicate = predicate.Or(att => att.ID == t);
}

//TABLE2.Where(predicate).Dump(); //works like a charm

IQueryable query = 
    from t1 in TABLE1
    where t1.TABLE2.AsQueryable().Any(predicate) //problem with this line
    select a;

query.Dump();
```

**UPDATE**

When using LinqKit in LinqPad add the reference to LinqKit.dll, uncheck Include PredicateBuilder and then also add LinqKit under Additional Namespace Imports tab.

Comment: Found a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522079/generated-sql-with-predicatebuilder-linqpad-and-operator-any. Haven't tested in VS, but it seems that it may be a problem with how I am writing it in LINQPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is

1. Call AsExpandable() on the `TABLE1`
   object
2. Call Compile() on the expression
   variable, when used on an EntitySet.

So your final query is

```
IQueryable query = 
    from t1 in TABLE1.AsExpandable()
    where t1.TABLE2.Any(predicate.Compile()) //the problem should disappear
    select a;
```

More information [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).