# Use LinqKit PredicateBuilder for related model (EF Core)

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linqkit

I want to use LinqKit's PredicateBuilder and pass the predicate into `.Any` method for related model.

So I want to build a predicate:

```
var castCondition = PredicateBuilder.New<CastInfo>(true);

if (movies != null && movies.Length > 0)
{
    castCondition = castCondition.And(c => movies.Contains(c.MovieId));
}
if (roleType > 0)
{
    castCondition = castCondition.And(c => c.RoleId == roleType);
}
```

And then use it to filter model that has relation to model in predicate:

```
IQueryable<Name> result = _context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(castCondition));
return await result.OrderBy(n => n.Name1).Take(25).ToListAsync();
```

But this causes a ``` System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'n.CastInfo.Any(Convert(__castCondition_0, Func``2))': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'. ```

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690298/how-to-use-predicate-builder-with-linq2sql-and-or-operator) and answer there suggests to use `.Compile`. Or [one more question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522079/generated-sql-with-predicatebuilder-linqpad-and-operator-any) that build an extra predicate.

So I tried to use extra predicate

```
var tp = PredicateBuilder.New<Name>(true);
tp = tp.And(n => n.CastInfo.Any(castCondition.Compile()));
IQueryable<Name> result = _context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(tp);
```

Or use compile directly

```
IQueryable<Name> result = _context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(castCondition.Compile()));
```

But I have an error about Compile: `System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'n.CastInfo.Any(__Compile_0)'`

So is it possible to convert the result from PredicateBuilder to pass into `Any`?

*Note:* I was able to build the desired behavior combining expressions, but I don't like that I need extra variables.

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<CastInfo,bool>> castExpression = (c => true);
if (movies != null && movies.Length > 0)
{
    castExpression = (c => movies.Contains(c.MovieId));
}
if (roleType > 0)
{
    var existingExpression = castExpression;
    castExpression = c => existingExpression.Invoke(c) && c.RoleId == roleType;
}
IQueryable<Name> result = _context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(castExpression.Compile()));
return await result.OrderBy(n => n.Name1).Take(25).ToListAsync();
```

So I assume I just miss something about builder.

*Update about versions:* I use dotnet core 2.0 and LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the code, one will assume that the type of `castCondition` variable is `Expression<Func<CastInfo, bool>>` (as it was in earlier versions of `PredicateBuilder`).

But if that was the case, then `n.CastInfo.Any(castCondition)` should not even compile (assuming `CastInfo` is a collection navigation property, so the compiler will hit `Enumerable.Any` which expects `Func<CastInfo, bool>`, not `Expression<Func<CastInfo, bool>>`). So what's going on here?

In my opinion, this is a good example of C# implicit operator abuse. The `PredicateBuilder.New<T>` method actually returns a class called [`ExpressionStarter<T>`](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Core/ExpressionStarter.cs), which has many methods emulating `Expression`, but more importantly, has **implicit** conversion to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and `Func<CastInfo, bool>`. The later allows that class to be used for top level `Enumerable` / `Queryable` methods as replacement of the respective lambda func/expression. However, it also prevents the compile time error when used inside the expression tree as in your case - the complier emits something like `n.CastInfo.Any((Func<CastInfo, bool>)castCondition)` which of course causes exception at runtime.

The whole idea of LinqKit `AsExpandable` method is to allow "invoking" expressions via custom `Invoke` extension method, which then is "expanded" in the expression tree. So back at the beginning, if the variable type was `Expression<Func<CastInfo, bool>>`, the intended usage is:

```
_context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(c => castCondition.Invoke(c)));
```

But now this doesn't compile because of the reason explained earlier. So you have to convert it first to `Expression<Func<T, bool>` **outside** of the query:

```
Expression<Func<CastInfo, bool>> castPredicate = castCondition;
```

and then use

```
_context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(c => castPredicate.Invoke(c)));
```

or

```
_context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(castPredicate.Compile()));
```

To let compiler infer the expression type, I would create a custom extension method like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LinqKit
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression<T>(this ExpressionStarter<T> expr) => expr;
    }
}
```

and then simply use

```
var castPredicate = castCondition.ToExpression();
```

It still has to be done **outside** of the query, i.e. the following does **not** work:

```
_context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(c => castCondition.ToExpression().Invoke(c)));
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I tried your code, and unfortunately I have a warning `The LINQ expression 'where __castCondition_0.Invoke([c])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.` So while it compiles and runs, the condition is not added to SQL and query selects all rows. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Actually you mention that `ExpressionStarter` can be caster to `Expression`. So this worked `var castExpr = (Expression<Func<CastInfo,bool>>)castCondition; context.Name.AsExpandable().Where(n => n.CastInfo.Any(castExpr.Compile())).Count()`; Inlining the variable does not work for some reason

Comment: Inlining does not work because the "expander" does not recognize `ExpressionStarter.Compile()`. Sounds like incomplete LinqKit job :(

Comment: Ahh, this is the type of Q&A that keeps me here! (I sometimes feel like quitting).

Comment: The advise above worked for me too. I got another error that hinted that the combination with async/await was not possible. After applying above tips and removing await and To...Async() all worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly related to the original question, but considering the following model :

```
public Class Music
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
public Class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

List<string> genresToFind = new() {"Pop", "Rap", "Classical"};
```

If you are trying to find all `Musics` that their genres exist in `genresToFind` list, here's what you can do:

Create `PredicateBuilder` expressions chain on `Genre` model :

```
var pre = PredicateBuilder.New<Genre>();
foreach (var genre in genresToFind)
{
    pre = pre.Or(g => g.Title.Contains(genre));
}
```

Then execute your query like this :

```
var result = await _db.Musics.AsExpandable()
    .Where(m => m.Genres
        .Any(g => pre.ToExpression().Invoke(g)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

`ToExpression()` is a generic extension method that we've created to convert `ExpressionStarter<Genre>` type to `Expression<Func<Genre, bool>>` :

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression<T> (this 
        ExpressionStarter<T> exp) => exp;
}
```

Also, you'll need `LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package.