# Use PredicateBuilder in SelectMany LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, predicatebuilder, linqkit

It's the first time I write here on stackoverflow.

I would like to use PredicateBuilder in a LINQ query with SelectMany.

I enter my code

```
public async Task<List<Articolo>> OttieniElencoArticoliFiltratoComplessoAsync
    (ExpressionStarter<Articolo> predicateArticolo,
        ExpressionStarter<ArticoloFornitore> predicateFornitore,
        ExpressionStarter<Categoria> predicateCategoria,
        ExpressionStarter<Magazzino> predicateMagazzino,
        ExpressionStarter<PrezzoVendita> predicatePrezzoVendita)
    {
        using (var database = DatabaseContext.NuovoDatabase())
        {
            var query = database.Articoli.AsExpandable();

            if (predicateArticolo != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(predicateArticolo);
            }

            if (predicateFornitore != null)
            {
                query = query.AsExpandable().SelectMany(a => a.ElencoArticoliFornitore.Where(predicateFornitore)).Select(fornitore => fornitore.Articolo);
            }

            if (predicateMagazzino != null)
            {
                query = query.AsExpandable()
                    .SelectMany(articolo => articolo.ElencoMagazzino.Where(predicateMagazzino))
                    .Select(magazzino => magazzino.Articolo);
            }

            if (predicatePrezzoVendita != null)
            {
                query = query.AsExpandable().SelectMany(articolo =>
                    articolo.ElencoPrezzoVendita.Where(predicatePrezzoVendita).Select(vendita => vendita.Articolo));
            }

            if (predicateCategoria != null)
            {
                query = query.AsExpandable()
                    .SelectMany(articolo => articolo.ElencoCategorie.Where(predicateCategoria))
                    .Select(categoria => categoria.Articolo);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

I create the predicate like this

```
        private ExpressionStarter<ArticoloFornitore> PredicateFornitore()
    {
        var ritornaNull = true;
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<ArticoloFornitore>();
        if (IsEnabledFiltroFornitore && FornitoreSelezionato != null)
        {
            ritornaNull = false;
            predicate = predicate.And(fornitore => fornitore.IdFornitore == FornitoreSelezionato.IdFornitore);
        }
        return ritornaNull ? null : predicate;
    }

    private ExpressionStarter<Categoria> PredicateCategoria()
    {
        var ritornaNull = true;
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Categoria>();
        if (IsEnabledCategoriaLivello1 && CategoriaLivello1Selezionata != null)
        {
            ritornaNull = false;
            predicate = predicate.And(categoria =>
                categoria.IdCategoriaLv1 == CategoriaLivello1Selezionata.IdCategoriaLv1);
        }

        if (IsEnabledCategoriaLivello2 && CategoriaLivello2Selezionata != null)
        {
            ritornaNull = false;
            predicate = predicate.And(categoria =>
                categoria.IdCategoriaLv2 == CategoriaLivello2Selezionata.IdCategoriaLv2);
        }

        if (IsEnabledCategoriaLivello3 && CategoriaLivello3Selezionata != null)
        {
            ritornaNull = false;
            predicate = predicate.And(categoria =>
                categoria.IdCategoriaLv3 == CategoriaLivello3Selezionata.IdCategoriaLv3);
        }

        if (IsEnabledCategoriaLivello4 && CategoriaLivello4Selezionata != null)
        {
            ritornaNull = false;
            predicate = predicate.And(categoria =>
                categoria.IdCategoriaLv4 == CategoriaLivello4Selezionata.IdCategoriaLv4);
        }

        if (IsEnabledCategoriaLivello5 && CategoriaLivello5Selezionata != null)
        {
            ritornaNull = false;
            predicate = predicate.And(categoria =>
                categoria.IdCategoriaLv5 == CategoriaLivello5Selezionata.IdCategoriaLv5);
        }
        return ritornaNull ? null : predicate;
    }
```

I tried this method on LINQPAD with fixed data instead of the PredicateBuilder and the query works.
But with the PredicateBuilder I get the .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.

How can I solve? I would like to be able to create a dynamic query that takes the parameters from the interface and returns the results.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You forgot to include code which uses PredicateBuilder.

Comment: I modified the post and added the code for creating the predicate

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706255/use-linqkit-predicatebuilder-for-related-model-ef-core/46716258#46716258. I would suggest using `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` rather than `ExpressionStarter<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFramework requires your predicates to be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` rather than `Func<T, bool>`. This is what `IQueryable.ToExpandable()` does. However, your Entity objects such as `articolo.ElencoPrezzoVendita` are virtual `ICollection` objects, so the predicate is reduced to `Func<T, bool>` which is incompatible with EF.

It doesn't exactly roll off the tongue but you could try something like this (I didn't know the structure of your objects) with database to ensure the `Expression` is used.

```
if (predicatePrezzoVendita != null)
{
    query = query.AsExpandable()
        .SelectMany(articolo =>
            database.ElencoPrezzoVendita
                .Where(x => articolo.ForeignKeyID == x.ID)
                .AsExpandable()
                .Where(predicatePrezzoVendita)
                .Select(vendita => vendita.Articolo));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much,
I solved my problem with this approach.