# Express query with multiple OR and filter on joined table with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

Here is my model

```
class Parent 
{ 
   int Id; 
   string Name; 
   List<Child> Childs; 
} // name is unique

class Child 
{ 
    int Id; 
    int ParentId; 
    string Name; 
    Parent Parent; 
} // couple (id, name) is unique
```

With a given list of couples **(parent name, child name)** I'd like to get the couples **(parent, child)** where child can be null if the parent with the given name exists but not the child. The SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN childs c ON c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'parent1' AND (c.name IS NULL OR c.name = 'child1')
   OR p.name = 'parent2' AND (c.name IS NULL OR c.name = 'child2')
   OR p.name = 'parent3' AND (c.name IS NULL OR c.name = 'child3')
   OR p.name = 'parent4' AND (c.name IS NULL OR c.name = 'child4');
```

I've tried expressing this query with Entity Framework Core using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for the Or and False methods

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Parent>()
    .Or(p => p.Name == "parent1" && p.Childs.Any(c => c.Name == "child1"))
    .Or(p => p.Name == "parent2" && p.Childs.Any(c => c.Name == "child2"))
    .Or(p => p.Name == "parent3" && p.Childs.Any(c => c.Name == "child3"))
    .Or(p => p.Name == "parent4" && p.Childs.Any(c => c.Name == "child4"));

var p = await _db.Parents
    .Include(p => p.Childs)
    .Where(predicate)
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

This is the closest I could get but this doesn't get the expected the result:

- if the child doesn't exist the parent is not present in the result set
- `Parent.Childs` contains all children of the parent instead of only the wanted one

Is my query expressible with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Why Child has ParentId and Parent?

Comment: Parent is the [navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). ParentId is optional but I don't think it changes the problem.

Comment: But it looks bad relationship

Comment: Indeed sorry, edited :)

Comment: Why do you use predicate builder instead of just using standard simple lambda expressions? There is NOTHING dynamic in those queries, the condition is static.

Comment: Do you realize that this is a pretty uncommon query: give me the parents and only the child by a given name, or parents without any children and skip the parents that only have children with other names. Esp. the last part seems uncommon. Is this intended?

Comment: @TomTom The list of couples is obviously dynamic hence the use of predicate builder :)

Comment: @GertArnold Yes I need to get parent and one of their child and I need to know if a parent doesn't have any child

Comment: OK, so that means that if `parent1` has two children, `child11` and `child12`, it won't appear in the list.

Comment: Ok not intended, thanks! To fix that, I use a right join instead and union with `name, NULL FROM parents` and apply a distinct on the parent id to avoid getting an extra null child for (parent, child) couples found. Writing this with EF Core seems impossible though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, the requirement now is: give me all parents, specified by name, and only one specific child per parent, if present. That is: parents having *other* children will appear in the result, but without children.

That sounds rather trivial, but it isn't. The gotcha is that it requires two filters, one on parents and one on children, in which the child filter is even parent-specific. A SQL query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM parents p1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT ch.*
    FROM children ch
    JOIN parents p2 ON ch.parentid = p2.id
    WHERE (p2.name = 'parent1' AND ch.name = 'child1')
       OR (p2.name = 'parent2' AND ch.name = 'child2')
       OR (p2.name = 'parent3' AND ch.name = 'child3')
       OR (p2.name = 'parent4' AND ch.name = 'child4') -- filter 2
) fc ON fc.parentid = p1.id
WHERE p1.name IN ('parent1','parent2','parent3','parent4') -- filter 1
```

For an EF LINQ query the parent predicate can be a simple `Contains`, but you'd want to build the predicate using a predicate builder. Here, for reason following later, I use [LINQkit.core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LINQKit.Core/).

To be able to build the predicates from one source I use a temporary structure (but I guess you already have something similar):

```cs
var filters = new[]
{
    new { ParentName = "parent1", ChildName = "child1" },
    new { ParentName = "parent2", ChildName = "child2" },
    new { ParentName = "parent3", ChildName = "child3" },
    new { ParentName = "parent4", ChildName = "child5" },
};
```

And prepare the predicates:

```cs
using LinqKit;
...
var parentNames = filters.Select(f => f.ParentName).ToList();
var childPredicateStarter = PredicateBuilder.New<Child>();
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    childPredicateStarter = childPredicateStarter
        .Or(c => c.Parent.Name == filter.ParentName && c.Name == filter.ChildName);
}
```

Now, ideally, the LINQ query would look like this (`db` is a context), working around the lack of filtering in `Include`:

```cs
var p = db.Parents
    .Where(p => parentNames.Contains(p.Name))
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Parent = p,
        Children = p.Children.Where(childPredicateStarter)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => p.Parent);
```

But that doesn't run because `p.Children` is `IEnumerable`, so `childPredicateStarter` implicitly converts to a `Func` instead of the required `Expression<Func>>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716258/861716) for an in-depth explanation.

The actual working version is:

```cs
// Convert to expression:
Expression<Func<Child, bool>> childPredicate = childPredicateStarter;

var p = db.Parents.AsExpandable() // <-- LINQKit's AsExpandable()
    .Where(p => parentNames.Contains(p.Name))
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Parent = p,
        Children = p.Children.Where(c => childPredicate.Invoke(c))
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => p.Parent);
```

The `AsExpandable` call converts the `Invoke` back into a proper expression tree that EF can translate into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> Parent.Childs contains all childs of the parent instead of only the wanted one

Filtered include is coming, but not implemented yet. I am a little at a loss on why you think it would actually filter at all, given that your code CLEARLY states to incldue ALL children...

> .Include(p => p.Childs)

Means include the children (btw., childs is bad english - the plural is Children). There is no filter there.

Regarding filtered include:

[Filtering on Include in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core)

Quoting the relevant part for here:

"Finally, this feature has been implemented starting with EF Core preview version 5.0.0-preview.3.20181.2 and will be GA in EF Core version 5.0.0"

But even then, you will have to filter (i.e. ptut a where into the include, not just tell it to get all of them).

Comment: Children, thanks for the correction. Assuming I'm using EF Core 5, tell me if I'm wrong but I would need a `Where` on the `Include` but also one on the `DbSet` like that
`_db.Parents.Include(p => p.Childs.Where(/* parent1 && child 1 || parent2 && child2 || ... */)).Where(/* parent1 || parent2 || ... */)
`