# How to choose different filtering condition for EF Core query in runtime

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a query that calculate stats based on DB data.
 Now I'd like to support passing time-ranges to it, but the solution I have now looks like a hack.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}

public class UserLogin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    //0 means fail, 1 means success
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}


var cutoffDate = request.From ?? DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-3);

var loginStats = await context.Set<User>()
                    .Where(a => logins.Contains(a.Login))
                    .Select(u => new
                    {
                        key = u.Username,
                        lastSuccessfulLogin = u.Logins.Where(l => l.Created > cutoffDate && b.Result == 1).Max(bo => bo.Created),
                        lastFailedLogin = u.Logins.Where(l => l.Created > cutoffDate && b.Result == 0).Max(bo => bo.Created),
                    }).ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.key, x => x, cancellationToken);
```

Can anyone suggest a cleaner approach (without hardcoded date)? I tried several tricks with expression trees, but they don't compile

Comment: That query will be inefficient, you seem to be querying the `Logins` table by using the `Users` set. What is the relation between `Logins` and `Users`? What would be that method's definition? What is the desired result?

Comment: the idea is to get last successful and failed login date for each user

Comment: @DejanJanjušević sorry I wasn't clear - added more code. login is an attempt to authorize (either successful or not)

Comment: What do you mean by *without hardcoded date*? A hard-coded date would be a fixed date value like `new DateTime(2020,7,20)`.

Comment: @GertArnold I mean if the `request.From` doesn't have a value, I'd like to not specify a boundary at all

Comment: so the question boils down to how do I build an expression that doesn't change the source and EF recognizes it

Comment: That's a common question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62459470/861716) for just one example.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I settled for this version:

```
var loginStats = await context.Set<User>()
                .Where(a => logins.Contains(a.Login))
                .Select(u => new
                {
                    key = u.Username,
                    lastSuccessfulLogin = u.Logins.Where(l => (request.From.HasValue && l.Created > request.From) && b.Result == 1).Max(bo => bo.Created),
                    lastFailedLogin = u.Logins.Where(l => (request.From.HasValue && l.Created > request.From) && b.Result == 0).Max(bo => bo.Created),
                }).ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.key, x => x, cancellationToken);
```

It removed the problematic fallback I had before (`DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-3)`)