# PredicateBuilder is not working on EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, predicatebuilder

```
public string[] FindAssets2()
{
    string[] result;

    using (var ctx = new StockContext())
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Asset>().Or(asset => asset.Symbol.Contains("TSLA"));

        result = ctx.Assets.AsExpandable()
        .Where(predicate)
        .Select(z => z.Symbol)
        .ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Just a piece of simple codes. It throws me

```
Exception: Unhandled expression type: 'Extension'
LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> original)
LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
LinqKit.Extensions.Expand(Expression expr)
LinqKit.ExpandableQueryProvider<T>.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

---

Below is my installed package

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="LINQKit.Core" Version="1.1.17" />
```

Any help would be appreciate. Many thanks!

Comment: What type does `predicate` say it is when you hover over it in Visual Studio?

Comment: and also if you just `ToString()` it - what does it look like?

Comment: ultimately, though, it looks whatever this is: is probably something to report to whoever wrote LinqKit

Comment: FOR ALL LATE VISITOR AND WHO WANT TO USE EFC WITH LINQKIT, PLEASE CONSIDER TO USE EFC 5.0.0-preview.2.20120.8 ON `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/5.0.0-preview.2.20120.8`. THIS IS THE ONLY VERSION WHICH WORK WITH LINQKIT AT THE MOMENT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that EF-core 5 doesn't play nice with `AsExpandable`. Or rather the other way around. It worked with EF3, but apparently Linqkit isn't resilient to library-specific idiosyncrasies of expression trees.

There is a work-around for this case. As expained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716258/861716), `predicate` is not an `Expression`, but an `ExpressionStarter`, which implicitly converts to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and `Func<T, bool>`. Therefore, queries with predicates on top-level entities (say: EF's `IQueryables`) work without `AsExpandable`:

```
result = ctx.Assets   // No '.AsExpandable()'
    .Where(predicate) // Implicit conversion of 'predicate' to Expression<Func<Asset,boo>l>
    .Select(z => z.Symbol)
    .ToArray();
```

The bad news is that without any fixes in this area, you won't be able to use `AsExpandable` when it's really necessary, for example for predicates on collection navigation properties.

Comment: Gertt,  the exception call stack contains LinqKit only methods, so isn't it the other way around - LinqKit doesn't play well with EFC (and any other code which emits custom (a.k.a. "extension") expressions) in the query expression tree?

Comment: @Ivan It's the combination of Linqkit and EF5. The same Linqkit version works with EF3. I don't know who's to blame. Of course, in a sense, it's Linqkit. EF5 works (sort of), add Linqkit to it and it breaks.

Comment: Apparently EFC5 uses custom expressions. Expression visitors should skip such expressions. LinqKit is outdated, the problem is there and should (if) fixed there and not in EFC.

Comment: @Ivan That I agree with. It's not the world's responsibility to please Linqkit.